# Access an objects keys when the object implements an interface?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In this demo there are two objects.  KEYS and KEYS2.  If we import KEYS in `index.ts` we get autocomplete for `K1` and `K2` because `KEYS` does not implement an interface.

With KEYS2 we don't because it implements an interface.

[This is the stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/object-keys-with-interface)

```
export interface IKeyObject {
  [key:string]: IKeyValue | any
} 

export interface IKeyValue {
  key:string
  value:any
}

export const KEYS = {
  K1: 'K1',
  K2: 'K2'
}

export const KEYS2:IKeyObject = {
  K1: { key:'', value:''},
  K2: {key:'', value:''}
}
```

Is there a way to implement the interface and get autocomplete for the keys on the object at the same time?

So in other words if we import KEYS2, and us it in a constructor:

```
constructor() {
    const v = KEYS.
}

VSCode will give us the properties on the object as autocomplete values?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your KEYS an enum and your IKeyObject a Record and things should work

The only type issue left is that you are using `IKeyValue | any` which is effectively just `any`.

```
export enum KEYS {
  K1 = "K1",
  K2 = "K2"
}
export type IKeyObject = Record<KEYS, IKeyValue | any>;

export interface IKeyValue {
  key: string;
  value: any;
}

export const KEYS2: IKeyObject = {
  K1: { key: "", value: "" },
  K2: { key: "", value: "" }
};
```

You should now be able to have autocomplete on KEYS2 to show K1 and K2 as options, though you'll have to remove `any` from IKeyObject to get more autocomplete.

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/object-keys-with-interface-h8hwr5?file=index.ts) with everything I mentioned and removing `any`.

Comment: `enum KEYS...` can be replaced by `type KEYS = 'K1' | 'K2';`. But the idea is correct.

Comment: You can't if you want to be able access KEYS like it's both a type and a value, which is what is currently being done in Ole's code. Using a string enum for this can be better because of that feature.